# Laravel register issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to create a register system, but i get this error:

> Route [register] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\app\views\account\register.blade.php)

Register.blade.php

```
    @include('_base')



<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Create account</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form" method="post" action="{{ URL::route('register') }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstname">firstname</label>
                        <input id="firstname" class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">lastname</label>
                        <input id="lastname" class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">E-mail adres</label>
                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create" />

            {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@include('_end')
```

Routes

```
Route::post('account/register', 'AccounController@register');
```

And this is my Controller

```
<?php

Class AccountController extends BaseController {

    public function getregister()
    {
        return View::make('account/register');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $rules = array(
            'firstname'     => 'required',
            'lastname'      => 'required',
            'password'      => 'required|min:4',
            'email'         => 'required|unique:user'
        );

        $messages = array(
            'firstname.required' => 'Voornaam is nodig',
            'lastname.required' => 'Achternaam is nodig',
            'password.required' => 'Er is een wachtwoord nodig',
            'email.required' => 'Een e-mail adres is nodig',
            'email.unique' => 'Dit e-mail adres bestaat al en kan geen 2x gebruikt worden'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::to('register')
            ->withErrors($validate)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {
            // Create User
            $user = new User;
            $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
            $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->save();

            Session::put('message', 'Je account is gemaakt');
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit url for form:

URL::to('accounts/register')

or add the name 'register' for route

```
Route::post('account/register', array('as'=>'register','uses'=>'AccountController@register');
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but if i want to register i get this error:

"Class AccounController does not exist"

Comment: Edit rout as shown above.  or   Route::post('account/register', array('uses'=>'AccounController@register');

Comment: So if i go to account/register then i get the form etc... But if i press the submit button, i get the error "Class AccounController does not exist"

Comment: Is this controller in controllers folder and change Class to class

Comment: Yes AccountController is in my Controllers folder. And Class has changed to class, but still doesn't work.

Comment: There is mismatch with class names AccountController and AccounController